# python: list index out of range error in code

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python, and really stuck at this.

Basically, I'm supposed to make a check code to check the last alphabet of the NRIC. My code works fine so long as there are 7 numbers (like there are supposed to be). However, my teacher just helped me find out that my code doesn't work whenever the number starts with 0. Below is my code.

```
def check_code():
    nricno = int(input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only). If you don't type an nric number, this code will fail."))

    NRIC = [ int(x) for x in str(nricno) ]

    a = NRIC[0]*2
    b = NRIC[1]*7
    c = NRIC[2]*6
    d = NRIC[3]*5
    e = NRIC[4]*4
    f = NRIC[5]*3
    g = NRIC[6]*2

    SUM = int(a + b + c + d + e + f +g)

    remainder = int(SUM % 11)
    leftovers = int(11 - remainder)

    rightovers = leftovers - 1 

    Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIZJ"

    checkcode = chr(ord('a') + rightovers)

    print(checkcode)

check_code()
```

This is the way the NRIC is supposed to be calculated, in the image below.

[NRIC calculation help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT0Dz.png)

Comment: What does 'a number that starts with 0' mean?

Comment: If the linked image is your actual assignment, then you are not doing it properly. You need to write a function that takes the NRIC string as an argument. Your function should not call the `input()` function, and it needs to return the check code. The logic in the code you posted does _not_ convert the check number to the check code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert the string input into an `int`, the leading zero is stripped away (e.g. `"0153444"` -> `153444`). When you convert back to a string again in the list comprehension, you won't get the zero back, so you end up with an NRIC list of [1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4] instead of [0, 1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4]. If you remove the `int` call, like this, you won't lose the leading zero.

```
# Change this:
nricno = int(input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only)..."))
# To this:
nricno = input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only)...")
```

Comment: There is also another issue with the code worth pointing out: what if someone doesn't type digits? What if they type `"ZZZZZZZ"` or  something like that? (This clearly being homework.)

Comment: @YeoZheYong I think that was the point of user268396's statement. It's an additional level of input validation you might want to do... :) Check they've input exactly 7 characters and that they're all digits before trying anything for instance...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact way to calculate the NRIC check code. If an invalid string is passed to the function a ValueError exception is raised, which will cause the program to crash. And if a non-string is passed TypeError will be raised. You can catch exceptions using the `try:... except` syntax.

```
def check_code(nric):
    if len(nric) != 7 or not nric.isdigit():
        raise ValueError("Bad NRIC: {!r}".format(nric))

    weights = (2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2)
    n = sum(int(c) * w for c, w in zip(nric, weights))
    return "ABCDEFGHIZJ"[10 - n % 11]

# Test
nric = "9300007"
print(check_code(nric))
```

**output**

```
B
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This code verifies if the input is made of 7 digits.

```
def check_code():       
    while True:

        nricno = input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only). If you don't type an nric number, this code will restart.")

        if len(nricno) == 7 and nricno.digits == True:
            print ("Works")
            continue
        else:
            print("Error, 7 digit number was not inputted and/or letters and other characters were inputted.")


    a = NRIC[0]*2
    b = NRIC[1]*7
    c = NRIC[2]*6
    d = NRIC[3]*5
    e = NRIC[4]*4
    f = NRIC[5]*3
    g = NRIC[6]*2

    SUM = int(a + b + c + d + e + f +g)

    remainder = int(SUM % 11)

    print(remainder)

    leftovers = int(11 - remainder)

    rightovers = leftovers - 1 

    Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIZJ"

    checkcode = chr(ord('a') + rightovers)

    print(checkcode.upper())

check_code()
```

Comment: Umm... you want `break` instead of `continue` in there else it's only ever going to print done and loop again even on valid input... Also, the check should be `if len(nricno) == 7 and nricno.isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

When you force your input as an int, the leading 0 will be interpreted as an error in Python 3. For example, `int(0351)` would not yield either `0351` or `351` but would just cause an error stating `invalid token`.

You should not force the input to be an int, but instead add an assert statement stating that the value inputted must be a 7 digit integer (or a regular statement as you've done if you prefer).

## Change this:

`nricno = int(input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only). If you don't type an nric number, this code will fail."))`

## To this:

`nricno = input("Please enter your NRIC(numbers only). If you don't type an nric number, this code will fail.")`