# Python Input Validation for both alphabets and numeric in one input

Tags: python

How do i do an input validation for NRIC numbers where there are both numbers and alphabets?
Example of NRIC number: S9738275G, S8937231H, S7402343B
ic=input('Enter NRIC Number: ')

Comment: `re.match(r"[\dA-Z]+")` should work.

Comment: FWIW, I wrote a function yesterday that determines the NRIC check code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38674235/4014959

Comment: Wikipedia has [Information about the Structure of the NRIC number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Registration_Identity_Card#Structure_of_the_NRIC_number.2FFIN)

Answer (score 1):

For your use case this should be enough:

```
>>> a = 'A12345678B'
>>> if a[0].isalpha() and a[-1].isalpha() and a[1:-1].isdigit(): print True
... 
True
>>> a = 'A12345678'
>>> if a[0].isalpha() and a[-1].isalpha() and a[1:-1].isdigit(): print True
... 
>>>
```

[0] first character, [-1] last character, [1:-1] second character to last but one character

Edit: Looking at PM 2Ring's comment, the NRIC number has a specific structure and specific method of creating the check digit/character, so I'd follow the code given in the link provided. Assuming that your NRIC number is the same obviously, as you didn't specify what it was.
Intriguingly: "The algorithm to calculate the checksum of the NRIC is not publicly available" Wikipedia

Comment: You could use `.isdigit`, then you wouldn't need the `try:... except`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Absolutely true but when I tested it I forgot the () in isdigit() and used int() instead. Only after I posted did a realise my typo.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a lot of different ways. Depending on the scale of your application, you might want something simpler or more complex.

If you want something rock solid, you can use a library such as [Pygood](https://github.com/kolypto/py-good) for that.

If you're looking for something in the middle, you can also use regex, see here [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address).

If you want to keep it as simple as possible, you can do a simple validation like so:

```
str = "B123"
if str[0].isalpha() and not str[1:].isalpha():
    # is valid
```

Comment: How about the number of alphabets and numerics needed to input?
In this case it would be 9 as ' S9738275G' has 9 alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
string = 'S9738275G';

if string.isalnum():
    print('It\'s alphanumeric string')
else:
    print('It\'s not an alphanumeric string')
```